# What is wrong with this piece of javascript code?

Tags: javascript

```
window.addEventListener("load", run, false);

function run() {
    var links = content.document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    var x = "";
    for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        x = x + "<p>" + links[i] + "</p>";
    }
    document.write(x);
}
```

I'm new to JavaScript, and I can't for the life of me figure it out.

Comment: document.write is being used. don't do that except from an inline-script (run during DOM construction, but that is still icky) or if you *really* want to "reopen" the document.

Comment: Your first step in figuring out what's wrong with your Javascript code should be hitting [your](http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg589507(VS.85).aspx) [browser's](https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/) [developer](http://getfirebug.com/) [tools](http://www.opera.com/dragonfly/). (At the very least the error console, and the JS debugger)

Answer (score 3):

Remove `contents` since it is not parent of document like `window` and I suspect there is no `content` object built-in JavaScript (though there is `contents()` function in jQuery):

```
var links = content.document.getElementsByTagName("a");
          ------^
```

Or you can also get all links with `document.links` like:

```
var links = document.links;
```

Comment: It would be helpful if you explained *why* `content` should be removed.